# Null coalescing operator and === don't return a boolean

Tags: php

```
$test = $_SESSION[ 'user_group' ] ?? null; // registered
$testCheck = $_SESSION[ 'user_group' ] ?? null === 'admin'; // registered
```

Why `$testCheck` is equal to 'registered' ? If `$_SESSION[ 'user_group' ]`value is `registered` why doesn't the triple === return a boolean ?

Comment: `($_SESSION[ 'user_group' ] ?? null) === 'admin'` ?

Comment: Because you're testing if null === 'admin'... Wrap it in ()

Comment: Very nasty operator precedence issue :) You can post as answer I will accept it