# Why does the PHP null-coalescing operator (??) behave irrationally with == and ===?

Tags: php, operator-precedence, null-coalescing-operator

```php
var_dump(3 ?? null);
var_dump(3 ?? null === null);
var_dump(3 === null);
var_dump(3 ?? 1 > 2);
var_dump(null ?? 1 > 2);
```

What do you consider the outputs to be?

> 3      # Expected
>  true   # Unexpected: I'd expect false
>  false  # This is also what I'd expect
>  3      # Wait, what?! Why is it 3 and not true??
>  false  # Oh so it only evaluates the right-side boolean if the left side is null??? How unexpected!

So the question is really this:

**Why does the PHP engine value `===` as higher than `??`? In what world would anyone *want* to compare it like `if ($count ?? (null === null))` when that is so counter-intuitive to the desired `if (($count ?? null) === null)`?**

Given `$count = 3; if ($count ?? 1 > 2)`, as a rational person, I would expect this to evaluate to `if ((3 ?? 1) > 2) -> if (3 > 2)` and return `true`. Instead, it evaluates to `if (3 ?? (1 > 2) -> if (3)`, which just happens to be truthy. But I don't think anyone would rationally want this evaluation...

It seems like a bug in the interpreter to me. Is there any good reason for this state of affairs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `??` is doing, but by your comments it appears clear you don't understand what it is actually doing. See the accepted answer on the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @WillemRenzema `Null coalescing ?? returns the first argument if it's set and is not null. Or the second argument otherwise`

OK try it... `if (3 === null)` should evaluate to `false` but it's evaluating to `true`.

Comment: @WillemRenzema My little test cases prove that the article you linked, and the PHP documentation, is not in fact true. or something else is going on.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith `if (3 === null)` is false.

Comment: Signposts that you could have found: [Why does php return the operand rather than the condition result if you use a ?? operator on one side of the condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75232323/2943403) and [Null coalescing operator and === don't return a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43427655/2943403)

Comment: This bugs me so much that it might cause me to fork PHP for a 2nd time in my career (first time was to add [] to PHP 5.2).

Comment: JavaScript also puts nullish coalescing way below `==`. Also, whenever I use a shiny new operator in my code I always look at the operator precedence table to make sure I am doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this result because `??` has lower precedence than any of the comparison operators (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)). Thus for example,

```
$count ?? null === null
```

evaluates as

```
$count ?? (null === null)
```

which evaluates to

```
$count
```

as `$count` *is* set.

For most of your tests, that then evaluates to `3` or `a`, which are both [truthy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), and so the condition test is true. Note that for this particular test, even if `$count` was unset, it would still evaluate true as `null === null`. So:

```
$count = 3;
if ($count ?? null === null) { echo "Noooo!!!\n"; } else { echo "Yes!!\n"; }
```

will output:

```
Noooo!!!
```

The one exception is where `$count` is set to `false`, where the result of the evaluation is then `false`, which gives you your expected result for

```
if ($count ?? true === true) { echo "Noooo!!!!\n"; } else { echo "Yes!!\n"; }
```

If you add parentheses to properly specify your desired operation, everything works as expected e.g.

```
$count = 3;
if (($count ?? null) === null) { echo "Noooo!!!\n"; } else { echo "Yes!!\n"; }
```

Output:

```
Yes!!
```

Demo showing faulty and corrected code for each example on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FFU0r)